# javascript code for html button: disable dropdown and make div appear based on that dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a javascript code that dynamically shows a div based upon the answer of a dropdown question in an html form:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.div-toggle2', function () {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
        $(target).children().addClass('hide');
        $(show).removeClass('hide');
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.div-toggle2').trigger('change');
    });
});//]]>
```

I additionally have a javascript code that disables this dropdown based upon a button click:

```
function disable() {
    document.getElementById("project_program").disabled = true;
```

Is there a way to combine the two codes...as in the button would disable the dropdown and show the div dynamically based upon the dropdown answer, all triggered by the button click?

Answer (score 0):

I would think about using `.prop()`. so: `$(""project_program").prop('disabled', true);`

in the context of what you're doing it would look something like this:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.div-toggle2', function () {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
    $(target).children().addClass('hide');
    $(show).removeClass('hide');
    // disable element on 
    $(""project_program").prop('disabled', true);
 });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.div-toggle2').trigger('change');
    });
});
//]]>
```